# Get stdout and stderr from jar tool bundled for OSX

Tags: macos, jar, executable-jar, jarbundler

I've created an OSX app using Jar Bundler from Xcode  following this howto: http://www.centerkey.com/mac/java/.
The tool works fine, is launchable and I stop it from the dock, the problem I'm facing is that this tools is a command line server, creates no windows and its stdout and stderr are needed.

Is there a way to create the bundle in which stdout and stderr are redirected to a log file or even a window somewhere once the .app is executed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to create a wrapper the just executed the file from the command line and with the installation process I placed it in /usr/bin

The content of this file is:

```
#!/bin/bash

/Applications/App_Name.app/Contents/MacOS/JavaApplicationStub

exit
```

So, now any user that wants the output from the commmand line in my too, can open a console and run the wrapper...